# Pandas: Append rows to DataFrame already running through pandas.DataFrame.apply

Tags: python, selenium, pandas

*Brief*: 
I am using `Selenium WebDriver` and `Pandas` for *Python 2.7* to make a web scraper that goes to a sequence of URLs and scrapes URLs on that page. If it finds URLs there, I want them to be added to the running sequence. How can I do this using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`?

---

*Code:*

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import re

df = pd.read_csv(spreadsheet.csv, delimiter=",")

def crawl(use):
    url = use["URL"]
    driver.get(url)
    scraped_urls = re.findall(r"(www.+)", element.text)
    something_else = "foobar"

    #Ideally the scraped_urls list would have to be unpacked here
    return pd.Series([scraped_urls, something_else])

df[["URL", "Something else"]] = df["URL"].apply(crawl)

df.to_csv("result.csv", delimiter=",")
```

The above scraper uses the column `"URL"` in `spreadsheet.csv` to navigate to each new `url`.
It then scrapes all strings on the page that matches the regex `www.+` to find URLs, and puts the results in the list `scraped_urls`.

It also gets the string `something_else = "foobar"`.

When it has processed all the cells in `"URL"` it writes a new file `result.csv`.

---

**My problem:**

I have had difficulties finding a way to ***add the scraped URLs*** in the list  `scraped_urls` to the column `"URL"` – so that they are inserted just below the "active" URL (retrieved with `use["URL"]`).

If the column in the source spreadsheet looks like this:

```
["URL"]
"www.yahoo.com"
"www.altavista.com"
"www.geocities.com"
```

And on *www.yahoo.com*, the scraper finds these strings via regex:

```
"www.angelfire.com"
"www.gamespy.com"
```

I want to add these as rows to the column `"URL"` below `www.yahoo.com`, so that they become the next keyword for the scraper to search:

```
["URL"]
"www.yahoo.com"         #This one is done
"www.angelfire.com"     #Go here now 
"www.gamespy.com"       #Then here
"www.altavista.com"     #Then here
"www.geocities.com"     #...
```

Is this possible? Can I on-the-fly append the DataFrame `df` that is already being run through `apply()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to use `apply` the way you envision. And even if there were a way,

- it would most likely require keeping track of how many items have already been iterated
  over so you would know where to insert new items into `df['URL']`
- inserting into the middle of `df['URL']` would require copying all the data from the current DataFrame into a
  new, larger DataFrame. Copying the whole DataFrame (potentially) once for
  every row would make the code unnecessarily slow.

Instead, a simpler, better way is to use a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29). The stack can be implemented by a simple list. You can push `df['URL']` onto the stack, then pop a url off the stack and process it. When new scraped urls are found, they can be pushed onto the stack and be the next items to be popped off:

```
import pandas as pd

def crawl(url_stack):
    url_stack = list(url_stack)
    result = []
    while url_stack:
        url = url_stack.pop()
        driver.get(url)
        scraped_urls = ...
        url_stack.extend(scraped_urls)

        something_else = "foobar"
        result.append([url, something_else])
    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["URL", "Something else"])

df = pd.read_csv(spreadsheet.csv, delimiter=",")
df = crawl(df['URL'][::-1])
df.to_csv("result.csv", delimiter=",")
```